# is it possible to create a generic method that will sort arrays and linked lists equally?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics, linked-list

I am working on an assignment that requires building a generic Java method that sorts a linked list or an array but I don't understand how that would be possible.

Comment: No, overload the method.

Comment: No, this can't really be done, because there's no common superclass of arrays and Collections (other than Object of course).  I guess you could make your method take an `Object` as an argument, and use `instanceof` to detect what it actually is; but it would be much better just to overload the method.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` sorting implementation should work with iterators to be efficient, because indexing and swapping elements without iterators would take linear time. Thus generic sorting of `LinkedList` and array (or `ArrayList`) doesn't make much sense.

If you would like to write a generic `ArrayList` and array sorting, for example, you could provide implementation with two lambdas, for getting and setting an element at some index:

```
private static interface Get<E> {
    E get(int index);
}

private static interface Set<E> {
    void set(int index, E e);
}

private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(
        Get<E> get, Set<E> set, int size) {
    // ... sorting algorithm
}

public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(E[] array) {
    // more verbose syntax if you use Java 7, but it shouldn't affect performance
    sort(i -> array[i], (i, e) -> { array[i] = e; }, array.length);
}

public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>, T extends List<E> & RandomAccess>
sort(T arrayList) {
    sort(arrayList::get, arrayList::set, arrayList.size());
}
```

I didn't measure, but this imlementation shouldn't be much slower, if any, than old simple approach, because JIT is able to inline lambdas seamlessly.